# Forming unitary matrices from identity relation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Given matrices $X_n$ where $n=0,1$ which satisfy $\sum_{n=0}^{1} X_n^{T}X_n = I$ what is the most natural way to form a $2 \times 2$ unitary matrix $U$ (which contains matrices as elements) where $X_n = X_{n0}$ (hence $X_0$ and $X_1$ are the first column of sub-blocks of the unitary matrix) i.e. $$ U = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
X_{0}& \cdot
\\ X_{1} & \cdot
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The only information you have is that the matrix
$$
M = \pmatrix{X_0\\X_1}
$$
Satisfies $M^TM = I$, which is to say that its columns are orthonormal (assuming the $X_i$ have real entries).  If you're trying to make a unitary matrix
$$
U = \pmatrix{X_0 & A\\X_1 & B}
$$
then what you're essentially doing is extending the columns of $M$ into an orthonormal basis for $\Bbb R^n$.  Gram Schmidt gives us one way to do this, but I wouldn't call this a "natural" approach.

---

Note that if $X_0,X_1$ are symmetric matrices satisfying $X_0X_1 = X_1X_0$ (as is the case in the comment described below), we can take
$$
U = \pmatrix{X_0 & -X_1\\X_1  & X_0}
$$
However, we run into trouble whenever $X_0^TX_1 \neq X_1^TX_0$

Comment: Is $C$ a real number between $-1/2$ and $1/2$?

Comment: Yes that's right

Comment: I see thanks, would this be a unique unitary matrix we could construct given the first column is $X_0$ and $X_1$?

Comment: No, it is not unique in that sense.